# Best Practice to report user location continusly and Google Latitude

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to make application that report user location to back end server. I had 2 choices:

- significant-change: I tried this, but accuracy is lower than what I'm looking for.
- Background Location update: accuracy is OK, but it's drain battery and it's not recommended by Apple, only for few  application.

I wonder if there is a method that gives good accuracy but without draining battery. for example, I notice Google Latitude app have good accuracy but it have no noticeable effect on battery.

any idea?